# This is for an ARG can you solve this code for me?

Tags: cipher, alternate-reality-game

aHR0cDovLzU0b2d1bTdnd3hodGdpeWEub25pb24vaW5zZXJ0b3Ivdmlldy8xMDVkYTI3YQ==

Comment: I came here for an argument!  Are you an Argentinian?  Or are you talking about an Alternate Reality Game (ARG)?  We expect puzzles to be, well, puzzling, but we also prefer them to be a bit less random than this.  Please spell out any acronyms that you're using, unless they're really and truly universal (ARG is not; I had to look it up); give us a pointer in the direction that you want us to go, and use correct English (punctuation).

Comment: What ARG is this from? Please provide a link or attribution to the original source.

Comment: When someone invites help from others with regards to an Alternate Reality Game, it is considered polite to introduce to it as if it were real, just like was done for the one asking.  Otherwise, you are simply being lazy.  You ask the question, suffixing with an tag indicating that it is an ARG and the colloquial name; a link to its main topic on the Unfiction, ARGnet, or Argology websites, et al, would be especially friendly.

Answer (score 4):

Well, Base64 decode gives:

> http://54ogum7gwxhtgiya.onion/insertor/view/105da27a

But that doesn't seem to go anywhere.

Oh but there's this:

> [.onion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.onion)

which probably means that's as far as I'm going.

Comment: It is Base64 and it results in an intelligible URI.  Seems to me like you went as far necessary, whether or not you are willing or able to explore a Tor network.

Answer (score 3):

## following @dan russell link into Tor:

> [image]

### The cypher?

> BMM LCGRNZULT IXLYJKPD KM NVPEAISLW HI EID VPLOUZA.

Comment: Any help with the cipher at all? i've tried most of the ones i know.

Comment: thats all i got. dont know how to continue. Is the game in english ?

Comment: yeah, we finally figured it out, it was a one time pad cipher, no wonder it stumped us.

Comment: "It is a riddle, wrapped in a mystery, inside an enigma; but perhaps there is a key." — Winston Churchill

Comment: @Grunt13, so the solution?